# Is it possible to develop NopCommerce on MAC?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, mono, visual-studio-2017, nopcommerce

After I found NopCommerces on open source projects I'm trying to debug and run this projects on MAC machine and got below error.
I'm using MACOS Sierra version 10.12.5 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, Mono version 5.0.1.

However, I'm trying to search some tutorial they said We could not run NopCommerces on MAC osx so I want to verify here it is true or not.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure with using mono!

But the last official release of nopCommerce is 3.90, which is targeting .NET Framework 4.5.1. And if you want to run it on mac, definitely you cannot.

But now as nopCommerce team announced upcoming version with .NET Core, yes you will be able to run it on mac too!

You can try to clone your project from [GitHub/nopCommerce](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce).

*Note: upcoming version is still under development, so you may face some error and issues.*

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**
nopCommerce 4.0 has been released, but still its targeting to .NET Framework 4.6 and not .NET Core. So you cannot run nopCommerce 4.0 to MAC or Linux.

Comment: Testing again and again

Answer (score 2):

We made 4.1 run on MAC doing the following:

Edited the path below to (NopFileProvider line 438) to:

```
public virtual string MapPath(string path)
{
      path = path.Replace("~/", string.Empty).TrimStart('/');   //.Replace('/', '\\');
      return Path.Combine(BaseDirectory ?? string.Empty, path);
}
```

and in project src/Build/ClearPluginAssemblies.proj we **removed** the following:

```
<Exec Command='dotnet "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=$(OutputPath)|PluginPath=$(PluginPath)|SaveLocalesFolders=$(SaveLocalesFolders)"' />
```